# Installation of outlook addin 2010

Tags: outlook

I have created a outlook addin 2010 using visual studio 2013 and also created a setup project for the same using windows installer.

I have done the following steps,

1. Added the project output and added exclude filter for manifest
2. published the addin project unser release mode
3. Added the manifest from published folder to the setup
4. Added the vsto file from release folder of the project
5. Added app.config into setup used by the project
6. Tried creating registry keys under UserMachine/Hive, but removed later

I have builded the setup as per the above creation and tried to install in other systems, but the addin is not getting loaded into outlook, also no resgitry keys available for the addin

```
Outlook Version - 32 bit
OS Version - 64 bit
```

For Msi also do we need to add trusted certificate and resgitry key setup?

Pls help me for this

Answer (score 0):

Signing the .exe file is not mandatory and won't affect installation.  Try right-clicking setup.exe and choose "Run as admin" to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 4 registry keys to the user/machine hive when installing from MSI as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx.

*User/Machine Hive*\Software\Microsoft\Office\*application name*\Addins\*add-in ID*

1. Description - REG_SZ - brief description of your addin
2. FriendlyName - REG_SZ - name for your addin visible in Outlook
3. LoadBehavior - REG_DWORD - set to 3 to load at Outlook startup
4. Manifest - REG_SZ - path to the installed manifest, including **file:///** prefix and **|vstolocal** suffix

When installing on a client machine, make sure it has the *Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime* installed (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178739.aspx). It's included by default in Office 2010. You can specify this as a prerequisite to the installer.